# Why do French dialog tags in books sometimes use inversion, but are not asking a question?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, syntaxe, incises, dialogues

I was reading a French book and noticed that some dialog tags appear inverted.  Where in English we would write:

> "Come here," he shouted.

In French I read:

> — Venez ici, crie-t-il.

Why not “il crie”?  Because it reads, “does he shout” or am I completely off base?

Comment: Incises are always inverted. See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/explication-de-lui-dit-il-et-lui-dit-elle/17325 and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13341/in-dialogue-how-do-we-separate-the-speakers-from-the-narrators-voice/13343

Comment: "Come here," shouted Laura.

Comment: There is a non negligeable possibility of saying "shouted he" in English too: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shouted+he+.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshouted%20he%20.%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Indeed, though archaic (in fact or in style): we don't invert with the pronoun nowadays, unlike French, but only with the full noun phrase. "Are you coming?" asked the sailor. "On Friday if all goes well," answered Geraldine wistfully.

Answer (score 5):

Pour avoir remplacé le tag *grammaire* par celui de *syntaxe*, je le payerai de quelques détails tant la chose n'est pas si anecdotique que cela.

D'abord pour faire observer que cette inversion du sujet nous vient de l'ancien français. Foulet la tient même pour *"le grand fait qui domine la construction médiévale*" ce n'est donc pas anecdotique. Elle aurait, toujours selon lui, des origines germaniques.

Et on l'observe, que la proposition soit proprement incise, rejetée après les paroles ou... devançant les paroles :

*"**Dient plusor** : « Ço est li definement, la fin del secle ki nus est en present. » (La chanson de Roland)

Le français moderne a conservé cette habitude sauf dans ce dernier cas que l'on pourrait alors aujourd'hui dire ainsi :

- *C'est la consommation des temps, **disent plusieurs**, la fin du monde que voilà venue* ou
- *C'est la consommation des temps, la fin du monde que voilà venue, **disent plusieurs*** mais
- ***Plusieurs disent*** : C'est la consommation des temps, la fin du monde que voilà venue

Plusieurs explications ont été avancées pour l'abandon de l'inversion dans le dernier cas. Certains avancent que les propositions intercalées ou rejetées sont brèves alors que celles qui précèdent peuvent être longues et que, dans ces cas, le français moderne tend à rétablir son "ordre naturel" sujet-verbe-complément.

Ordre naturel ou je ne sais quoi d'autre, une chose est sûre, le parler populaire ne l'aime pas cette inversion et a trouvé la solution magique pour s'en dispenser : ***Que***

Cette pratique semble assez *récente* (relativement à l'ancien francais... eh! ;-) ) Et Balzac est je crois le premier à la consacrer :

- *" Pauvre petit! Nous allons mourir ensemble, **qu'elle dit** en regardant son enfant "* (in *La femme de trente ans*, 1844)

Zola embrayera le pas (*"C'est bon, **qu'il ma dit** en foutant le camp"*)

Céline qui poussera jusqu'à carrément... éliminer sujet et verbe : *"« Ha! Ce cher Céline! » Très chaleureux."*

Un pas n'avait encore jamais été franchi. L'inversion subsistait tout de même avec un nom en tant que sujet. Queneau le franchira allègrement :

*" Ça c'est une riche idée, Zazie dit. "*

Alors... l'inversion dans les incises dans le littéraire *"branché"* ? on laisse Philippe Djian conclure ? Allez... :

*"Bas les pattes, tas de connards !!! qu'elle faisait."* (In 50 contre 1)

Answer (score 1):

May I also add that in English, **inversion like this isn't uncommon, though rather obsolete. Especially in older writing**, one can easily find

> *"'Come here,' shouted he..."*

This seems rather archaic, but "he" does function correctly as a subject in this case, mostly in archaic usage. I think I remember this being used in A. A. Milne's works, but I have no source for that. I know that as a child learning English, inversion after the question like that never confused me, I just thought either was okay depending on context.

The inversion is especially prolific in even more modern writing in the form of

> *"'Come here,' shouted the man"*

"The man" replaces "he". In this usage, no native English speaker would balk upon hearing it. Generally this is used in writing that narrates an event, although it's still considered slightly more archaic than not inverting the sentence.

EDIT: Source found for the Milne example; Was on Winnie-the-Pooh ride at Disney and saw some pages of his stories as decorations.